# What is the source of the Dragon Ball Saiyan bond folklore?

Tags: culture, dragon-ball-series

I have been reading a lot of fanfiction and noticed they all nearly use the Saiyan bond, bite marks, and telepathic connection for mates. However I cannot seem to find the source of the information for this.

Is there any reliable info about this?

Comment: Could you provide examples/works of the said fanfictions that suggest `they all nearly use the sayian bond, bite marks, and telepathic connection for mates.`?

Answer (score 3):

According to [a writing about Bulma/Vegeta fandom by adimra](http://www.adimra.100megs6.com/bvfaq.html), all of this concepts were born from fandoms and applied to their fanfictions.

Regarding the Saiyan bond and telepathic connection,

> **Is there really a bond? Where did it come from?**
>
> The bond has become a staple in B/V (ed: Bulma/Vegeta) fanfiction and many believe that it was in fact, invented in fanfiction - but that is only part true. In 1995, a writer going by the pen name 'Katchan,' started her ambitious 50 chapter 'Saiyajin,' it was her "Dragonball withdrawal whim." I believe she was the first to give the *bond* its name, and it further inspired Nora Jemison's 'The Third Bond.'
>
> Now, were Bulma and Vegeta ever truly bonded in the Anime? Though it was never clearly stated as a bond, Bulma and Vegeta had a deep connection that was the basis for this. *When Vegeta sacrificed himself to Buu, Bulma immediately sensed something was wrong, even though she wasn't near him. Fanfiction has further romanticized this by including telepathy or the sharing of memories etc. as part of the bonding process*. While that is just an interpretation of what may have happened, it's more based on fact than fanfiction (hurray ^_^).
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Regarding bite mark,

> **Ok, so what about this biting thing that usually comes with a bond?**
>
> Along with the bonding, a bite on the neck is usually involved with Bulma and Vegeta romances. Unlike bonding, the bitemark has no concrete basis on the anime. I believe biting was first used in either 'Saiyajin' or 'The Third Bond' or perhaps both. I believe one rumour was that *the reason Bulma wore those scarves in the Buu Saga was to cover up her Saiyan hickey* ;p! Over the years though, the bite mark has come to symbolize a number of things like ownership, marriage etc. and I'm sure that B-Chan's 'Lemon Chapters' had a hand in that.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

In conclusion, I believe this is just fans' speculation based from shown evidences on the series.